# EasyMock logging calls

Tags: eclipse, log4j, easymock

I have my nice mock objects and unit tests that succeed.
However nothing appears in the console.
Is there a way to log every calls on any mock objects and the matchers it tries ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured and turned on logging?